# MongoDB aggregate failing with afterClusterTime error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm running a MongoDB 4.0 replicate set and accessing it from NodeJs but have run into a problem using aggregation.

When the number of results returned by aggregate exceeds the default or specified batchSize I get the following error:

```
MongoError: afterClusterTime is not allowed for this command
at ...\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:581:63
at authenticateStragglers (...\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:504:16)
at Connection.messageHandler (...\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:540:5)
at emitMessageHandler (...\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:310:10)
at Socket.<anonymous> (...\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:453:17)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
at TCP.onread (net.js:559:20)
```

I've narrowed the problem down to the use of sessions,  is this an issue with MongoDB or the NodeJS driver, or is there something I missed in how to do this.

For reference, the following is enough to exhibit the problem.

MongoDB 4.0 replicate set spawned using the [Zero-config MongoDB runner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-rs) (run-rs --version=4.0.0)

NodeJs

package.json

```
 {
  "name": "aggregate_test",
  "dependencies": {
    "mongodb": "^3.1.4",
    "yargs": "^12.0.5"
  }
}
```

index.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var args = require('yargs').argv;
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017,localhost:27018,localhost:27019?replicaSet=rs', {useNewUrlParser: true})
    .then(function (client) {
        var session = args.session !== false ? client.startSession() : undefined;
        var db = client.db('test');
        var collection = db.collection('test_collection');
        return collection.insertMany([
                    {item: 'one'},
                    {item: 'two'},
                    {item: 'three'}
                ], {session: session})
            .then(function () {
                return collection.aggregate(
                    [{$match: {item: {$exists: true}}}],
                    {session: session, cursor: {batchSize: 1}});
            })
            .then(function (cursor) {
                /* Error occurs as result of this call */
                return cursor.toArray();
            });
    })
    .then(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
        process.exit(0);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.error(err);
        process.exit(1);
    });
```

Comment: It seems that `getMore` doesn't work with causal consistent sessions. The error goes away if I set sufficiently large `batchSize` so that the whole result fits into a single batch.